# Pandas compute hourly average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where time is a float relevant to the dataset:

```
 Time            Value
-47.88333         90
-46.883333        23
-45.900000        66
-45.883333        87
-45.383333        43
```

The time column ranges from -48 to 0. What I would like to do is compute the average value on every half hour from -47.5 through -.5. **For example:**

-47.5 would be the average of all values that fell between -48 and -47 and -46.5 would be the average of all values that fell between -47 and -46. If there is no value I would like to carry forward the previous average.

Resulting in an output that would look like:

```
 Time            Value
-47.5             90
-46.5             23
-45.5             65.33
-44.5             65.33
-43.5             65.33
```

Will this need to be a custom function since the time column is not a datetime object?

Comment: what does that time value represent? -46.5 = 46 hours 30 minutes before some point in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a groupby pretty easily:

```
(df.groupby(df.Time.apply(lambda x: np.floor(x) + 0.5))
   .mean()
   .Value
   .reindex(np.arange(-47.5, -42.5))
   .ffill())

Time
-47.5    90.000000
-46.5    23.000000
-45.5    65.333333
-44.5    65.333333
-43.5    65.333333
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try binning the time variables with `pd.cut`:

```
#change the bins arg to modify the size of the bins
df.loc[:, 'TimeBin'] = pd.cut(df.Time, bins=[i for i in range (-48, 0)])
#groupby the time bin and take the mean:
df[['TimeBin', 'Value']].groupby('TimeBin').mean()
```